# Why the outputStream isn't working without inputStream?

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I have tried to connect a PHP script on localHost, but the script isn't accessed without the presence of inputStream. Accidentally I made the code working, but don't know why it is working in presence of inputStream but not in absence of inputStream

```
 try {
        String url= "10.0.2.2/arrival.php";
        URL loginurl= new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection http= (HttpURLConnection)loginurl.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        http.setDoInput(true);

        OutputStream out= http.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bfwr= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out,"UTF-8"));
        String post_data= URLEncoder.encode("renter_id","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(renter_id,"UTF-8");

        bfwr.write(post_data);
        bfwr.flush();
        out.close();
        bfwr.close();

        InputStream inpt= http.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bfrdr= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpt,"iso-8859-1"));
        String line="";
        String result="";
        while((line=bfrdr.readLine())!=null){
            result+=line;
        }
        bfrdr.close();
        inpt.close();
        http.disconnect();

        return "";

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you get the response from script by means of inputstream. if you don't have it, you have to means to see the response. and if you don't see the response, it doesn't mean that the script is not accessed

Comment: That makes sense better than my google searches, Thanks. @mangusta

Comment: just to avoid confusion, I've made a typo in my comment above, should be read as `have no means` instead of `have to means`